Was Prussia afraid of German unity during the first Schleswig War?
Engels once sustained that Prussia was afraid of German unity during the first Schleswig war. Is there any historical validity to this claim? This would be very interesting since only a decade later Prussia went on to do exactly that, unite Germany.

And who, from the outset, supported Denmark? The three most counter-revolutionary powers in Europe -- Russia, England and the Prussian government. As long as it was possible the Prussian government merely pretended to be waging a war -- this is evidenced by Wildenbruch's Note, by the alacrity with which the Prussian government, on the representations of England and Russia, ordered the withdrawal from Jutland, and finally by the two armistice agreements. Prussia, England and Russia are the three powers which have greater reason than anyone else to fear the German revolution and its first result -- German unity: Prussia because she would thereby cease to exist, England because it would deprive her of the possibility of exploiting the German market, and Russia because, it would spell the advance of democracy not only to the Vistula but even as far as the Dvina and the Dnieper. Prussia, England and Russia have conspired against Schleswig-Holstein, against Germany and against the revolution.  Marxist.org


"the German Confederation supported the rebels as a federal war (Bundeskrieg) according to its statutes [...] with most of the German troops being provided by Prussia." (wiki)

"This would be very interesting since only a decade later Prussia went on to do exactly that" The Prussian king actually refused the crown of Germany in 1849, so no real surprise here.

@Jan: That's misleading. From Brittanica "When, on April 3, 1849, Frederick William refused the imperial crown offered by the national assembly in Frankfurt am Main—because as a true conservative he would accept it only from the German princes—he destroyed the constitution drafted by that assembly. " Frederick William IV had no interest in being a constitutional monarch beholden to a legislature.

The whole article should probably be read somewhat tongue in cheek. Or at least one would hope so, given sentences like "apart from Holberg, Danish literature is a poor imitation of that of Germany". But it reflects a mood that was somewhat common in Germany at the time it was written. Which is in September 1848, after the treaty of Malmö had been signed in late August.

The armistice of Malmö led to fierce protests in Germany, particularly among the revolutionary left. In their view, Prussia, under pressure from the great powers (Britain and Russia), had abandoned the revolutionary government in Kiel. When the Imperial Parliament in Frankfurt accepted the treaty, the so-called September riots shook the city.

For more details on the September riots, see this German wp article.

What is wrong with the answer in Wikipedia:FirstSchleswigWar?

However, in the aftermath of the revolution of 1848, which had damaged the prestige of the House of Hohenzollern as fighting had broken out in the streets of Berlin, it was felt essential to take a bold foreign policy step which would restore the prestige of the Prussian state.[6] The king and his advisors were not German nationalists, but the German liberals opposed to the absolutist Prussian monarchy were. The king's advisors believed that a German nationalist war would win support for the Prussian state from many of those liberals who were opposed to it.[6] Wikipedia:FirstSchleswigWar


I have edited the question to focus on the aspect I found most interesting.

I don't understand why this doesn't answer the revised question. I shall have to think further.
